# IDirect3DDevice9::Present fails to move frame content in full screen mode

Tags: winapi, directx

I'm using next code to display frame content in the middle of the window. When I have window mode it's ok, but when I'm using full screen mode it fails - frame content is in the top left corner. Return value(hr) is S_OK.

```
RECT src = {0, 0, viewport_width, viewport_height};
RECT dst = {0, (window_height - viewport_height) / 2, viewport_width, viewport_height + (window_height - viewport_height) / 2};

hr = pd3dDevice->Present(&src, &dst, 0, 0);
```

Do you have any idea why? Do you know other way to copy all frame buffer content to a specific position in window?

Comment: To draw anything anywhere, you usually want textured quads; that's the standard go-to and can actually be faster than other methods (copy-on-swap, blit, etc) in many cases since the hardware is *extremely* optimized to draw a triangle.

Answer (score 0):

You can only specify a rectangle if the device was created with D3DSWAPEFFECT_COPY.

Comment: The device is created with D3DSWAPEFFECT_COPY for both window and full screen.

Comment: It is probably faster to use discard. To render in the middle you can adjust the viewport.

Comment: I can't adjust viewport because there is a lot of code that assumes the viewport is on 0,0. I can't change this code :|

Comment: Another option is to use a render target.